# Chrome extension that gets the DOM elements of the page user is visiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am new to extension development so I am making an extension which gets the product's name or price from the `DOM` of the page user is visiting. I made it but i am facing a problem that every single time i have to reload the page.

For example, If user is at flipkart.com say and visiting some product, then as soon as i click on specific product (of course the product's page is going to be loaded) i have to click on my extension icon then and only then it gets the data i need.

if the page is fully loaded and then i click on my extension icon i dont see the output i need, instead it prints nothing on console.

In other words, what should i do so that, i dont have to worry about clicking on the extension icon and the data i need, is automatically in my `popup.html`.

```
manifest.json
```

```js
{
 "manifest_version" : 2 ,
 "name" : "myextension",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "browser_action":
 {
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"
 },
 "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": ["https://www.amazon.in/*","https://www.flipkart.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js","mycontentscript.js"]
     }
    ],
 "background" :{
  "scripts" : ["background.js"]
 }, 
 "permissions": [
    "*://flipkart.com/*","*://amazon.in/*", "tabs", "http://localhost/*", "webNavigation" //local host added
  ],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*/* default-src 'self'  "
}
```

mycontentscript.js

```
var prdname=document.getElementsByClassName('_3eAQiD')[0].innerText; //just getting the name of prduct

myob ={     
     "prd" : prdname

  };
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(); 
    port.postMessage(myob); //sending product name to myscript.js
```

```
myscript.js
```

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(res){
    alert(res.prd); ///just alerting here 
    });
    });
```

the main thing is it wont give me alert when the DOM is fully loaded . 
In other words, i have to click on the extension icon, at the same time when my product page loads otherwise it wont work!

Can you please help me fix this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run some code to save product page in background script. And later load it from you popup script (which i assume where `myscript.js` is laoded)
So this code goes to background script which is running all the time

```
//background.js
var productName
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  switch (request.command) {
    case "saveProduct":
      productName = request.productName
      break
    case "loadProcut":
      return productName
      break
  }
})
```

The following to content script that is loaded when user opens the page specified in manifest.json

```
// mycontentscript.js
var prdname=document.getElementsByClassName('_3eAQiD')[0].innerText
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    command: "saveProduct"
    productName: prdname 
})
```

And finally this loads the product name from the popup js

```
//  myscript.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    command: "loadProcut"
},function(productName){
  console.log(productName)
  alert(productName)
})
```